# How to fill a label with text read from a file .msg

Tags: c++

I want to fill a label with some text read from a file.msg. I think i've somehow managed to read from the file but now i need to fill the label with what i've read.

```
void __fastcall TErrorPanel::lblOpMsgErClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  char OutBuf[500];
  char OutBuf2[500];
  static int Func_exec = 0;
  if (Func_exec == 0)
  {
    Func_exec = 1;
    if (tpgm_cfg.TestMod.RejectModule == 0)
    {
      GetMessage(1, SYSMSGIMG, OutBuf, gPathMsgFile);
    }
    else
    {
      GetMessage(2, SYSMSGIMG, OutBuf2, gPathMsgFile);
    }
    Func_exec = 0;
  }
  return;
}
```

The GetMessage custom function, at the moment it shows MsgNF, it looks like it isn't picking up the content of the OutBuf

```
void GetMessage(int Code,char *Section, char *OutBuf, char *PathMsgFile, int InsErrCode)
{
  char buff[512],Msg[500],sCode[10];
  char *p;
  int cmpres;
  long rOffset = 0;

  itoa(Code,sCode,10);
  ::GetPrivateProfileString(Section, sCode, "MsgNf", buff, sizeof(buff), PathMsgFile);
  rOffset = ::GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, "Offset", 0, PathMsgFile);
  cmpres=strcmp("MsgNf",buff);
   if (cmpres==0)
   {
     sprintf(Msg,"Message[%ld]: Not Found !",Code + rOffset);
   }
  do
  {
    p = strchr (buff , '|');
    if(p != NULL)
    {
      *p = '\n';
    }

  }while(p != NULL);

  strcpy(OutBuf, buff);
  if (strcmpi(SYSERRORMSG,Section)==0)
  {
    sprintf(buff,"Error[%ld]-%s", Code + rOffset, OutBuf);
    strcpy(OutBuf,buff);
    rmLastErrorCode = Code;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: You are asking about how to do it in [tag:c++builder], right?

Comment: What does that `GetMessage()` function do? It has the same name as the Windows function[`GetMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) but totally different arguments.

Comment: it is the GetMessagre function maybe i've made a mistake there? why totally different args?

Comment: Regarding [`GetPrivateProfileString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring): "_This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications. Applications should store initialization information in the registry._"

Comment: Do `SetLastError(0);` before you call `::GetPrivateProfileString()` and log `GetLastError();` after it returns. Do the same for `::GetPrivateProfileInt()`. Do you get anything else than `0` logged?

Comment: ah ok, nono the problem isn't into the getmessage i can ensure you that it is working but maybe i'm using it in the wrong way

Comment: You do not check the error codes from neither `GetPrivateProfileString` nor `GetPrivateProfileInt`. To do so, call `SetLastError(0);` first, then call `GetPrivateProfile*()` then check what `GetLastError();` returns. If it returns anything but `0` it failed. Print out the error code and then look it up.

Comment: How can you be sure when you do not check the error code?

Comment: this function it is used in ther 90 places correcly, i'm sure it is stable... the problem now is that it is working more or less but it shows only MsgNf

Comment: You are thinking about it the wrong way. It can be used in 10000000 places and work correctly - until that day when it gets some arguments that it can't deal with or something unforseen happens. Take care of the error messages so that you are 100% sure that the calls succeed.

Comment: you're sadly right, but it is so easy this thing that it seems impossible that can't properly work as i expect

Comment: i've found the issue...i was saving the wrong file.msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you generally set the text to display:

```
label_name->Caption = "Text to display";
```

However, I don't know how to fit that into the code you've shown.

Comment: I think that I've to put it after the getmessage,consider that the text caught by the getmessage is into the Outbuf/outbuf2 the source is a file.msg where is written  1=message 2=message2 ,those two elements are into a section that for now is called SectionImg

Comment: Sure, if you get null terminates strings from your `GetMessage` function, that sounds correct.  `label_name->Caption = OutBuf;` or `label_name->Caption = OutBuf2;`

Comment: @codroipo Did it work to set the text using the `TLabel`'s `Caption` property?

Comment: no i thought that was a problem with the triggher that i use to  but inside the triggher there is a show for the entire form. The execution isn't touching anything of the code shown.

Comment: at the moment i've implemented your suggestion like this Lable->Caption = OutBuf;

Comment: @codroipo Ok, that should work if `OutBuf` is a null terminated string.

Comment: it is showing herself but it's giving MagNF intead of the error message

Comment: @codroipo What is `MagNF`? This sounds more and more like a problem that has nothing to do with setting the text displayed by a `TLabel`.

Comment: i've managed to show a text into the label but is a message error, somehow it isn't able to pick up the text from the OutBuf... that is the only thing that now concerns me

Comment: Then you should post a new question regarding that. Include the details needed to understand. Right now `GetMessage()` is a black box for the rest of the world. Only you know what's going on in there. Also use the tags. If you are asking C++builder specific questions (like how to assign values to [tag:vcl] objects) - tag your question [tag:c++builder] and [tag:vcl].

Comment: i've posted it above